# List view take full view

Tags: android, listview

[image: First Image]                [image: Second Image]

I am new android development. Below i attach my layout file.

In my layout i have one `ListView` and one `EditText` with `ImageButton`. When i insert task in `EditText` and press the `ImageButton` that task will be added in `ListView` one by one.

My problem is suppose i add more than 4 task means the `EditText` with `ImageButton` view is not visible because the list items take that place.I add my screen shot above of them  please give solution thanks...

```
    `**Layout:**        
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/todaytaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="TODAY" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/tomorrowtaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="TOMORROW" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/futuretaskbtnid"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
            android:text="FUTURE" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativelayoutid"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
                android:hint="Add Today Task" />

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:src="@drawable/addtask" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should not hardcode listview height instead force it to use remaining space on screen.

Comment: Would be working in a RelativeLayout (which could be used of course) - but how would one do this in a linear layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have a single `Relative layout` or you can try the below. You can have single relative layout and place your widgets relative to each other.

The other option is to add the linearlayout button widgets as a header. Also add the editext and image button as a footer to the listview.

```
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/todaytaskbtnid"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="TODAY" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tomorrowtaskbtnid"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="TOMORROW" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/futuretaskbtnid"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:text="FUTURE" />
</LinearLayout>
     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_above="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_below="@+id/ll"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        </ListView>
        <EditText 
            android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:hint="Add Today Task"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Edit: using a single relative layout

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:id="@+id/rl"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


     <ListView
            android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_above="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        </ListView>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:text="Button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
            android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
            android:text="Button" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"

            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Add Today Task" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Grpahical editor screen shot

[image]

Samsung galaxy s3 screen shot

![enter image description here][2]

Since you asked forscreen shot by adding more items

![enter image description here][3]

```
![enter code here][1]
```

From the discussion

Have row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="38dp"
        android:text="TextView" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

You can use the first xml as activity_main.xml

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText ed;
    ImageButton ib;
    ListView lv;
    ArrayList<String> aa;
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter;
    CustomAdapter cus;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ed= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edittextidAddTodayTask);
        ib= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imagebuttonidAddTodayTask);
        aa = new ArrayList<String>();
        lv= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.frontpagetasklistid);
        for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
        {
            aa.add(""+i);
        }
        cus = new CustomAdapter();
         //arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, aa);
         lv.setAdapter(cus);
        ib.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.i("...............", "...............");
                aa.add(ed.getText().toString());
                cus.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

        });
    }

   class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter
   {
       LayoutInflater mInflater;
       TextView tv;
        public CustomAdapter()
        {
            this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);  
        }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return aa.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return 0;
    }

    public View getView( int arg0, View arg1, ViewGroup arg2) {

        if(arg1==null )
        {
             arg1=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, arg2,false);
        }
             tv= (TextView) arg1.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
             tv.setText(aa.get(arg0));


        return arg1;
        }

   }

}
```

Comment: @Satheesh try the above also you can have a single relative layout for better efficiency.

Comment: in graphical layout it will be working fine but when i run this programmatically it have the same error...

Comment: @Satheesh that's not possible. specify the height and width of your editext and image button. specify the height for your buttons above listview. and place the listview below buttons and above editext. it will work

Comment: this is working but the first list item visible under the button.

Comment: @Satheesh i have shown you the way. but it may not me exact match of what you want. you can add margins and modify accordingly. I don't see any reason it won't work.

Comment: @Satheesh check the screen shot of the device.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33176/discussion-between-satheesh-and-raghunandan)

Answer (score 1):

I make some changes in your layout:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:weightSum="10">

            <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dip"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:weightSum="30"
             android:orientation="horizontal" 
             >
             <Button
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_width="0dip"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 />
             <Button
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_width="0dip"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 />
             <Button
                 android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                 android:layout_width="0dip"
                 android:layout_weight="10"
                 />
             </LinearLayout>
         <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
             android:layout_height="0dip"
             android:layout_weight="8"
             >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

            </ListView>
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
             android:layout_weight="1"
             android:weightSum="10"
             android:orientation="horizontal" 
             >

            <LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dip"
             android:layout_weight="1"

             android:orientation="horizontal" 
             >

            <EditText 
                android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="Add Today Task"
                android:layout_weight="10"
                android:drawableRight="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:background="@android:color/black"
                />
   /// I remove the button . there is no need of it.
            </LinearLayout>


        </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Now call the your drawableRight click listener to handle the action

```
yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new RightDrawableOnTouchListener(keyword) {
        @Override
        public boolean onDrawableTouch(final MotionEvent event) {
            // do whatever you want
        }
    });
```

Comment: But my imagebutton reside in edittext end of the position so how its possible please give .....

Comment: set android:drawableRight="@drawable/your_icon" inside your edit text property

Comment: and also no need of image button now so you can remove the weightsum for the parent layout as here now there is only one child control and that is edittext. so make the width of the edittext to fill parent now

Comment: But is visible next of the edittext.but i want inside the edittext

Answer (score 1):

You can use listView.addFooterView(view); Here the view refers to the view which contains the edit text and the add button.

Comment: i am also try this but same problem occur

Answer (score 1):

You can add a footerview to the listview and make it invisible. In footer view, copy the layout of the bottom bar which includes EditText and ImageButton. Just create a new layout file and paste this xml into the file.

```
 <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/relativelayoutid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="invisible" >

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
                    android:hint="Add Today Task" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:src="@drawable/addtask" />
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Add this layout as a footerview in your Listview. That way your Listview will never hide the original bottom bar. Don't forget to make it invisible.

Answer (score 1):

Hi please try using weight for list view

Example by editing your xml is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="3" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/todaytaskbtnid"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
        android:text="TODAY" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/tomorrowtaskbtnid"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
        android:text="TOMORROW" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/futuretaskbtnid"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/buttonselector"
        android:text="FUTURE" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/frontpagetasklistid"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativelayoutid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edittextidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="@drawable/edittextselector"
            android:hint="Add Today Task" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imagebuttonidAddTodayTask"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/addtask" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```